# How to read binary file to text in python 3.9

Tags: python, text, binary

I have a `.sql` files that I want to read into my python session (python 3.9).  I'm opening using the file context manager.

```
with open('file.sql', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

When I print the text, I still get the binary characters, i.e., `\xff\xfe\r\x00\n\x00-\x00-...`, etc.

I've tried all the arguments such as `'rb'`, `encoding='utf-8`, etc., but the results are still binary text.  It should be noted that I've used this very same procedure many times over in my code before and this has not been a problem.

Did something change in python 3.9?

Comment: I just tried to read `.sql` file with `rb` and everything is okay. Here is my screenshot https://prnt.sc/18MpPEaxku_h.

Comment: yeah @DimitrijeCiric that should work but for some reason it doesn't for me.

Comment: did you tried other encoding? `latin-1`, `cp1250`, `utf-16` ?

Comment: first two bytes `\xff\xfe` looks like `BOM` (`Byte Order Mark`) and table at the end of page [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) shows that `\xff\xfe` can means encoding `UTF-16-LE`

Comment: As @furas noted it looks like your file (assuming it's meant to be text and not binary) is encoded as UTF-16-LE. Were these files created on a MS Windows system? It would be simplest to recreate them using UTF-8. If that isn't possible then google how to read UTF-16-LE.

Comment: if this is real `UTF-16-LE` then you need `open('file.sql', 'r', encoding="utf-16-le")`. There is also module `chardet` which can try to recognize encoding `chardet.detect(bytes)` but I don't know if it recognize `utf-16-le`

Answer (score 1):

First two bytes `\xff\xfe` looks like `BOM` (`Byte Order Mark`)
and table at Wikipedia page [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) shows that `\xff\xfe` can means encoding `UTF-16-LE`

So you could try

```
with open('file.sql', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
```

---

**EDIT:**

There is module [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) which you may also try to use to detect encoding.

```
import chardet 

with open('file.sql', 'rb') as f:  # read bytes
     data = f.read()

info = chardet.detect(data)
print(info['encoding'])

text = data.decode(info['encoding'])
```

---

Usually files don't have `BOM` but if they have then you may try to detect it using example from [unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding/check-for-bom-markers](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html#check-for-bom-markers)

```
from codecs import BOM_UTF8, BOM_UTF16_BE, BOM_UTF16_LE, BOM_UTF32_BE, BOM_UTF32_LE

BOMS = (
    (BOM_UTF8, "UTF-8"),
    (BOM_UTF32_BE, "UTF-32-BE"),
    (BOM_UTF32_LE, "UTF-32-LE"),
    (BOM_UTF16_BE, "UTF-16-BE"),
    (BOM_UTF16_LE, "UTF-16-LE"),
)

def check_bom(data):
    return [encoding for bom, encoding in BOMS if data.startswith(bom)]

# ---------

with open('file.sql', 'rb') as f:  # read bytes
     data = f.read()

encoding = check_bom(data)
print(encoding)     

if encoding:
    text = data.decode(encoding[0])
else:
    print('unknown encoding')
```